# About the cylinder $C_f=((X\times[0 ; 1])\sqcup Y)/\sim$, where $\sim$ is the relation $(x,0)\sim f(x)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm doing an exercise that is far more difficult than the others on my notes. I've been thinking about it but I don't know if my approach is the correct one.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous function. We define the cylinder $C_f=((X\times[ 0;1])\sqcup Y)/\sim$, where $\sim$ is the relation $(x,0)\sim f(x)$.
>
> i) Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are included in $Cf$.
>
> ii) Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are closed subspaces.
>
> iii) Prove that $r:C_f\to Y$ where $r([(x,t)])=f(x)$ and $r([y])=y$ is a retraction and it's continuous.

My loose thoughts on the tree parts:

> i) Here I took the inclusion $i: X \to C_f$ where $i(x)=[(x,0)]$. So obviously $X$ it's included in $Cf$. Same with $Y$, we take the map $i: Y \to C_f$ where $j(y)=([y])$. Is that correct?
>
> ii) $X$\ $C_f=\emptyset$, obviously is open (and closed) in the topological space $C_f$. Y is more difficult, because we don't know if $f$ is exhaustive. $Y$ \ $C_f=f(X)$ that is open (because $f$ is continuous). So both $X$ and $Y$ are closed.
>
> iii) Here we have to see that $r\circ j=id_y$, where $j$ is the inclusion $j:Y \to C_f$, but I'm stuck.

Am I right? I see everything like a little bit "obvious", so almost sure I'm doing mistakes in every part.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For i) you will need to show that these maps are topological embeddings. For ii), $X$ is not open in $C_f$, and you should be considering $C_f-X$, anyway. You also need $C_f-Y\cong X\times [0,1)$. For both parts you will need to consider the topology on $C_f$. (hint: it is a quotient of $X\times I\sqcup Y$. For iii) you have $r\circ j(y)=r[y]=y$, so it is a retraction. Continuity is what you will need to consider and for this you must again think about the topology on $C_f$.

Answer (score 0):

i)  The relation $(x,0) \sim f(x)$ says that the slice $X \times \{0\}$ is a copy of $f(X) = Y$.  However, every other slice (choice of second coordinate from $(0,1]$ is a copy of $X$, so, for example, $\{(x,1) \in C_f : x \in X\}$ is a copy of $X$.  There is still a little work to show that the pointwise bijections "is a copy of" are homeomorphisms.

ii)  It is far easier to notice that the projection $X \times [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]: (x,y) \mapsto y$ is continuous.  The two slices we mentioned above are closed if they are the (full) preimages of closed subspaces of $[0,1]$.  (And you know a lot more about closed subspaces of $[0,1]$ in the subspace topology of the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, so this should be easy.)

iii)  I agree with [Tyrone's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557021/let-x-and-y-be-topological-spaces-let-fx-to-y-be-a-cont-function-we-de#comment5278533_2557021).  The work to show here is that you actually have continuous maps.

Comment: I have to see that the inclusion maps $i(x)=([x,0])$ and $j(y)=([y])$ are homeomorphisms? Or there's an easy way to prove that they're embeddings?

On the other hand, I don't understand your approach in ii). Could you explain it a little?

Thanks a lot Eric.

Comment: ii):  Definition of continuous function: the preimage of an open set is open.  Consequence: the preimage of a closed set is closed.  Consequence: the preimage of $\{0\}$, a closed set, is $Y$, a closed set and the preimage of $\{1\}$, a closed set, is $X$, a closed set.